# Automatically switching to magit diff window from magic-status

Tags: emacs, buffer, elisp, diff, magit

I'm trying to add a hook to *magit* so that when a `*magit-diff`* buffer (using the `magit-diff-mode` major mode) opens inside an Emacs window, my cursor moves (from the magit-status window) to that window.

I tried to add a hook to `magit-diff-mode-hook` but couldn't make it work at all.

Which hook (if any) should I use and what could I do to make that window active?

P.S: if there are two diffs window (say because another magit-diff from another project would be open), I'd like to go to the one that just did just open.

Answer (score 2):

`magit-diff-mode-hook` is not very helpful since its functions are run when the  diff-buffer is just constructed and still active. Only `display-buffer` is called for the diff-buffer. So, the focus goes back to the caller. But, the diff-buffer is the next one on the window-stack. So, the following should work (please, test it more thoroughly than I did):

```
(defadvice magit-diff (after switch-to-diff activate)
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: I shall test it... By the way thanks for all your recent posts about Emacs! That said I realized *magit* was even better than I thought: there are already quite a few shortcuts wired in *magit* which allow to save time, so I'm not sure I'll "mess" with it. I may instead try to learn the proper way of using *magit* : )

Answer (score 1):

Magit actually does what you are asking for. When I use `d` or `D` the diff is displayed in another window and that window gets focus. I am not sure if it always did that though, I might have changed `magit-diff-*` to behave that away at some point, instead of whatever it did before I touched it.

If that doesn't match your experience (with the development version) then please open an issue.